# Displaying content saved with localStorage onto a div

Tags: javascript, local-storage, user-input

I am trying to get a button to open a textarea - I managed - then the user writes an address onto the textarea and clicks on save and the address is saved on the screen - struggling here with the final bit. My output is "[object MouseEvent]" rather than the address

```
const billingAdd = document.getElementById('billing');
const addButton = document.getElementById('add');
const textBoxBillAdd = document.getElementById('billing');
const newBillAdd = document.getElementById('new-billing');

textBoxBillAdd.hidden = true;

let saveNewBillAdd = (input) => {
    localStorage.textBoxBillAdd = input;
    newBillAdd.innerHTML = localStorage.textBoxBillAdd;
    textBoxBillAdd.hidden = true;
    addButton.innerHTML = 'Edit';
}


function newBillingAdd() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        addButton.innerHTML = 'Save';
        textBoxBillAdd.hidden = false;
    });
}

async function addNewBillAdd() {
    const neww = await newBillingAdd()
    .then(addButton.addEventListener('click', saveNewBillAdd));
}

addButton.addEventListener('click', addNewBillAdd);
```

I also share my HTML below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href='test.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2"><img src='./icons/profile-picture.png'></td>
                <td class='John'>John Hamish Smith<button>Edit</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>01.03.1959
                <div><button>Edit</button></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class='u' class='space-up'>
                    <u>Home address</u>
                
                </td>
                <td class='space-up'>
                    <button>Edit</button>
                    <button>Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td colspan="2" class='u'>47 Fashion Street E1 6PX </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class='u' class='space-up'><u>Billing Adress</u></td>
                <td class='space-up'><button id='add'>Add</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td colspan="2"><textarea id='billing' placeholder="Type here" cols='28' rows='8'></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td colspan="2" id='new-billing'></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <script src="./test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

Update:

When I look at LocalStorage on Devopps it gives me:

`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'event.target')`

which I am guessing is because my input is not defined?
But again I tried the following (code snippet):

```
const newAddressButton = document.getElementById('button');
const textBox = document.getElementById('textarea');
const newAddress = document.getElementById('new-address');

textBox.hidden = true;

let saveNewAddress = (input) => {
    textBox.innerHTML = input;
    localStorage.setItem('textBox', input.target.value);
    newAddress.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('textBox');
    textBox.hidden = true;
    newAddressButton.innerHTML = 'Edit';
}


function newAdd() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        newAddressButton.innerHTML = 'Save';
        textBox.hidden = false;
    });
}

async function addNewAddress() {
    const myAddress = await newAdd();
    .then(newAddressButton.addEventListener('click', saveNewAddress));
}

newAddressButton.addEventListener('click', addNewAddress);
```

prior and still nothing comes up, even though the error goes away.

---

Update 2:

I have now tried to alter the function (see below). On my DevOps show that what I type is stored so the issue is on the storage retrieval I am guessing? Any help will be much appreciated as I have been stuck on this for sometime

```
let insertNewBillAdd = () => {
    let input = textBoxBillAdd.value;
    localStorage.setItem('input', input);
}
let saveNewBillAdd = () => {
    newBillAdd.hidden = false;
    let see = localStorage.getItem('input');
    newBillAdd.value = see;
    textBoxBillAdd.hidden = true;
    addButton.innerHTML = 'Edit';
}

function newBillingAdd() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        addButton.innerHTML = 'Save';
        textBoxBillAdd.hidden = false;
    });
}

async function addNewBillAdd() {
    const neww = await newBillingAdd()
    .then(insertNewBillAdd).then(addButton.addEventListener('click', saveNewBillAdd));
}

addButton.addEventListener('click', addNewBillAdd);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace these:

```
localStorage.textBoxBillAdd = input;
newBillAdd.innerHTML = localStorage.textBoxBillAdd;
```

with

```
localstorage.setitem('textBoxBillAdd', input.target.value)
newBillAdd.innerHTML = localStorage.getitem('textBoxBillAdd');
```

Comment: Thank you @YTG, I no longer get the error but the value is not showing, not saved on id='newBillAdd' as I would have wanted. I have tried to add a definition of 'input' as textBoxBillAdd.innerHTML but still does not produce any outcome

Comment: I have understood, please correct me if I am wrong, that .target take the value/innerHTML from the button 'Save' which is where I click and hence becomes the target. So what I have managed is for the field to have written 'Save' on it - any suggestions?

Comment: In your devTools, check the local storage. Is the key actually created? is there any value?

Comment: It gives me: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'event.target'). which I am guessing is because my input is not defined? But again I tried adding textBoxBillAdd.innerHTML = input; prior and still nothing comes up, even though the error goes away

Comment: Can you edit your question to be a snippet so I can reproduce the error?

Comment: I have just edited with an update above, thank you!

Comment: It's still not a snippet:)

Comment: ooooups, I hope I got it now - have adjusted language for more 'general' - is that it?